# Choose folders to be ignored during search in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Right now when I use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to search for files, the fuzzy matching appears to operate over all files in the current project. Unfortunately, this includes a number of files from build and vendor directories. So, for instance, if I want to search for all JavaScript files and do <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and type `.js` in, the file and symbol results include around 1500 hits and all of them except the two ones are complete noise.

Is there a way to specify certain directories to be ignored for purpose of search?

Comment: Hmm, wait a minute, in 2019 ⌘O means "Open File...", and I doubt VS Code has much control over whatever (OS-specific) search facilities you might see there.  It *might* be able to filter the files to only certain extensions?

Comment: Is this similar to Command +T now? I see stuff from node_modules when I prefix m search with # in the global search.

Comment: **Related settings** I was looking for: `search.useIgnoreFiles` `search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles` (tells search whether to pay attention to what's in gitignore to filter out what gets searched - I prefer this off in general, if I want it to filter something out I'll explicitly let it know)

Comment: Press `CTRL + ,`  then `search.exclude`.

Comment: Make sure to reload the window after setting a new exclude pattern.

Answer (score 1271, accepted):

**Temporary Exclusions**

From the search function, click the ellipsis to show the `files to include` and `files to exclude` text boxes. Enter any files and folder to exclude (separated by commas).

[image: Picture of temporarily excluding files/folders by entering them in to the files to exclude text box.]

**Persistent Exclusions**

From menu choose `File ➡️ Preferences ➡️ Settings ➡️ User/Workspace Settings` and filter default settings to `search`.

- `User` settings will apply to all workspaces
- `Workspace` settings will apply only to this workspace

You can modify the `search.exclude` setting (copy from default setting to your user or workspace settings). That will apply only to searches. Note that settings from `files.exclude` will be automatically applied.

**Toggling search exclusions**

You can (sometimes accidentally) toggle if these exclusions are enabled or disabled when searching using the gear icon in the `files to exclude` text box. Click the ellipsis, then the gear icon to toggle.

[image: Picture of toggle instructions in the search field.]

[Additional documentation on configuring settings in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

**If the settings don't work**

You might also need to Clear Editor History (See: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6502).

***Example***

I am developing an EmberJS application which saves thousands of files under the `tmp` directory.

If you select `WORKSPACE SETTINGS` on the right side of the search field, the search exclusion will only be applied to this particular project. And a corresponding `.vscode` folder will be added to the root folder containing `settings.json`.

This is my example settings:

```
{
    // ...
    "search.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/bower_components": true,
        "**/tmp": true
    },
    // ...
}
```

**Note**: Include a ** at the beginning of any search exclusion to cover the search term over any folders and sub-folders.

***Picture of search before updating settings***:

Before updating the settings the search results are a mess.

[image: Picture of search before updating settings]

***Picture of search after updating settings:***

After updating the settings the search results are exactly what I want.

[image: Picture of search after updating settings.]

Comment: this has stopped working for me in the recent version... any idea why?

Comment: Works in the latest v1.7.2 for mac. One possible gotcha: double-check that you wrapped the setting in a top-level object - without this it fails to work without a warning.

Comment: Seems that in 1.8 they've gone back (?) to having separate User and Workspace settings options in the Preferences menu.

Comment: I had to close and re-open the application to apply the new settings.

Comment: Is there a way to make this apply to the "Quick Open" feature?  Ctrl+P on PC and Cmd+P on Mac.  When i search for files using this feature, they still show up.

Comment: Make sure to clear your editor history for this to work. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6502

Comment: Also note that there is `"files.exclude"` which will completely hide the files from the workspace.

Comment: The menu option now is:
`File -> Preferences -> Settings`
And then you have to select either one of the tabs `USER SETTINGS` or `WORKSPACE SETTINGS` (at the right side of the search field)

Comment: I had to run the command "clear editor history" (see here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6502#issuecomment-273697138) and restart VS Code for this to work for me.

Comment: Note that it is possible to turn the search exclusion off when searching files. In the search area, expand the "files to exclude" input box and make sure that the gear icon is selected. This will ensure your search exclusion settings are honored.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/how-can-i-choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search/48847197#48847197

Comment: @shotty but how to exclude an extension from the search (eg: `.lnk`)? This failed: `"search.exclude": {        ".lnk": true,   },`

Comment: The gear icon in the "files to exclude" is super subtle—at least in my current theme, it's tough to see whether it's even selected. Super non-obvious!

Comment: concerning the exclude field: **you must specify the relative path** (from the workspace  if you don't write anything in `include file`, VS code search in it. If you set an `include file`, specify the relative path from this point.)

Comment: I have "**/node_modules/" and "**/node_modules/*" added to both "search.exclude" and "files.exclude" in both user and workspace settings and yet node_module files still show up in search! How hard can it be to exclude a folder!

Comment: If the folder is a git project, with a `.gitignore` file, then the search will exclude the patterns included on that file. People are asking to do the same for file visibility, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38878#issuecomment-540520454). I hope someday it will be implemented

Comment: Setting `"search.useIgnoreFiles":false` was also required for me, as mentioned at https://dinohensen.nl/vscode-enable-searching-node-modules See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: It's not working for me, is there anything else to do (from the settings.js file)?

Comment: for me, it fixed I needed to use `Developer: Reload window` (type `>reload` after CMD/CTRL+P)

Comment: BTW, to clear the editor history, search the command palette (i.e., shift+ctrl+p, search for Clear Editor History).

Comment: @RobertWaddell thank you sir. Must have accidentally toggled off my global exclusions. You saved my sanity!

Comment: @Ryan I would go crazy if I didn't have node_modules excluded from search. If you really need to look up the modules sources, have a separate VS Code window open just for that, with the node_modules folder open. Just switch between the windows to look up the docs. Another way would be to set up a custom .code-workspace file, you can list multiple folders there, add your project root and a separate node_modules folder. E.g. "folders": [
  {
   "name": "root",
   "path": "./"
  },
  {
   "name": "node_modules",
   "path": "node_modules/"
  }
 ]

Answer (score 231):

Make sure the 'Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files' cog is selected
[image]

Comment: How would one exclude multiple folders?

Comment: @WouterVanherck you would just add a comma to separate each file or folder you want to exclude. Example: `./src/public/,src/components/`

Comment: Thank you! I never would have guessed that having that icon clicked was turning on and off my workspace settings. I spent hours thinking I was doing my settings incorrectly.

Answer (score 74):

**Update April 2018**

You can do this in the search section of vscode by pre-fixing an exclamation mark to each folder or file you want to exclude.

[image]

Comment: Exactly! perfect

Comment: What exactly does the ! do in this case? Putting `node_modules/*` would exclude node modules already.

Comment: In 2018 VSCode was laid out with `include/exclude` so the `!` would exclude. See the accepted answer for an update.

Answer (score 49):

I'm an idiot so it took me a while to realize this, but make sure that the **Gear** icon is clicked on the global search so your settings can be applied.

[image: Visual Studio Code Gear Icon on Search clicked]

Comment: you're not an idiot because this is the answer that fixed it for me, I must have accidentally clicked that icon in the past, it's so not obvious that this little icon controls this and it's barely noticeable when it's enabled or disabled

Comment: You're certainly not an idiot for missing that wonderful piece of UX, but can you tell me how yours is different than [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48847197/1028230), if it is -- well, beyond this answer being in dark mode? ;^D

Comment: @ruffin did not notice the earlier answer ha! I guess mine has better UX (the arrow) ;)

Comment: Ha! 22 people and counting agree, so who am I to argue? Least I didn't miss something obvious; thanks.

Comment: Why is this button even a thing?  In what universe do I set global settings and then want to turn off those global settings via a confusing button?

Answer (score 43):

If these are folders you want to ignore in a certain workspace, you can go to:

`AppMenu > Preferences > Workspace Settings`

Otherwise, if you want these folders to be ignored in all your workspaces, go to:

`AppMenu > Preferences > User Settings`

and add the following to your configuration:

```
//-------- Search configuration --------

// The folders to exclude when doing a full text search in the workspace.
"search.excludeFolders": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "path/to/other/folder/to/exclude"
],
```

The difference between workspace and user settings is explained [in the settings docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Comment: If it's outdated, please either update it, or delete it to avoid confusion and possible downvotes!

Comment: I think the link changed to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: The reason why this answer should be accepted is because it saved the configuration file.

Comment: As of 2022-07-20 this is the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54646625/634586

Answer (score 32):

If I understand correctly you want to exclude files from the vscode 
fuzzy finder. If that is the case, I am guessing the above answers are for older versions of vscode.
What worked for me is adding:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/directory-you-want-to-exclude": true,
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/CVS": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true
}
```

to my `settings.json`. This file can be opened through `File`>`Preferences`>`Settings`

Comment: FYI, this **also** excludes those files from the explorer window, not just search

Answer (score 21):

Hi you need to find settings and add a new exclude pattern for history files

[image: VSC Screenshot]

Comment: This one is the right answer for 2023.

Comment: You can also add multiple items in one line: `{**/*.svg,**/*.npm,**/*.csv}`

Answer (score 18):

Create this file in your vscode project

`.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/Pods": true,
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/*.code-search": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I added this to settings.json

```
    "search.exclude": {
      "**/node_modules/**": true,
    }
```

after need enable it in settings panel

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is to **comma-separate the folders you want to ignore** in "files to exclude".

1. Start workspace wide search: CTRL+SHIFT+f
2. Expand the global search with the three-dot button
3. Enter your search term
4. As an example, in the *files to exclude*-input field write `babel,concat` to exclude the folder "babel" and the folder "concat" in the search (make sure the exclude button is enabled).
5. Press enter to get the results.

Answer (score 8):

Since it was not mentioned before and some users wanted to know how to exclude multiple files or folders (temporarily) in an ad-hoc search:

You can **exclude multiple files and folders** from the search with a **comma-separated** list of simplified **globbing patterns** (as described in [VS Code's glob.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/base/common/glob.ts) source:

```
/**
 * Simplified glob matching. Supports a subset of glob patterns:
 * * `*` to match one or more characters in a path segment
 * * `?` to match on one character in a path segment
 * * `**` to match any number of path segments, including none
 * * `{}` to group conditions (e.g. *.{ts,js} matches all TypeScript and JavaScript files)
 * * `[]` to declare a range of characters to match in a path segment (e.g., `example.[0-9]` to match on `example.0`, `example.1`, …)
 * * `[!...]` to negate a range of characters to match in a path segment (e.g., `example.[!0-9]` to match on `example.a`, `example.b`, but not `example.0`)
 */
```

And don't forget to activate the **(*⚙-*)** **Use Exclude Settings and Ignored Files** button on the Search Details panel **(*...*)** (following Shotty's explanations).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

After you setup the search.exclude and file.exclude mentioned on the previous answers, run the command  "Clear Editor History" (Use the Command Palette to do that - CTRL + SHIFT + P).

Only after that the excluded files will not appear on your quick open menu.

Update: You can run the command "Clear Command History" too. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to exclude 1 of the Workspace folders completely, but found this to be difficult, since regardless of the exclusion patterns, it always runs the search on each of the Workspace folders.

In the end, the solution was to add `**` to the **Folder Settings** search exclusion patterns.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Forget aboves for vscode exclude search pattern, try to below pattern it is working for any folder in vscode last version!

!../../../locales/*

for example i have searched like below
[vscode example clude settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLe2A.png)

files to include: 
***.js**

**files to exclude: 
**/node_modules,!../../../locales/*,!../../../theme/*,!../../admin/client/***

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple folders in your workspace, set up the `search.exclude` on each folder. There's a drop-down next to `WORKSPACE SETTINGS`.

[Folder Settings Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsIUd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Extending the [most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33418660/2963448), now there is an extension to achieve what is described there to toggle quickly in a GUI way. It's called [Explorer Exclude](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterSchmalfeldt.explorer-exclude). You can install this with this command:

```
ext install PeterSchmalfeldt.explorer-exclude
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am sure it must be resolved now but I just wanted to contribute my solution as well which may be easy and useful for someone.

simply type below line in `exclude field` of the search

> `*/node_modules/*`

No need to set anything in the setting files of your workspace/VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways / layers to exclude things from VS Code search features (which includes [the Search View](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files), [Search Editors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-editor), [Quick Open](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation), and Quick Search):

- The `search.exclude` setting, which takes an object mapping glob patterns to a boolean for whether to exclude resources matching the pattern. Note that this setting inherits pattern from the `files.exclude` setting.
- The `search.useIgnoreFiles` setting, which specifies whether to also follow .gitignore files and .ignore files in the workspace (defaults to `true`).
- The `search.useParentIgnoreFiles` setting, which specifies whether to also follow ignore files in parent directories of the current workspace.
- The `search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles` setting, which specifies whether to also follow the user's global git ignore file.
- See also the `search.quickOpen.includeHistory` and `search.quickOpen.includeSymbols` settings.

In the Search View, or in a Search Editor, click the three dot menu to the right of the search field to open up extended search options, where you can specify a comma-separated list of glob patterns to match files to exclude from the search results. Note also that there is a button at the right side of the "files to exclude" field to toggle whether to "Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files".

For docs about search patterns, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options.

Note that there are some differences between glob pattern interpretation in the exclusion settings versus the "files to exclude" search fields. Quoting the above linked docs:

> Note that glob patterns in the Search view work differently than in settings such as `files.exclude` and `search.exclude`. In the settings, you must use `**/example` to match a folder named `example` in subfolder `folder1/example` in your workspace. In the Search view, the `**` prefix is assumed. The glob patterns in these settings are always evaluated relative to the path of the workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude all from subfolders works like this (version 2019)

**include**

```
./db
```

**exclude**

```
./db/*
```

Answer (score -2):

I wanted to search for the term "Stripe" in all files except those within a plugin ("plugin" folder) or within the files ending in ".bak", ".bak2" or ".log" (this is within the wp-contents folder structure of a wordpress install).

I just wanted to do this search one time and very quickly, so I didn't want to alter the search settings of my environment.  Here's how I did it (note the double asteriks for the folder):

- Search Term: Stripe
- Include Files: {blank}
- Exclude Files: *.bak*, *.log, **/plugins/**

[Here's what it looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGypN.png)

Answer (score -4):

Create a file with .gitignore & put the folder or file name which one you want to ignore.

**to ignore everything below node_modules folder**

```
echo node_modules/ > .gitignore
```

Comment: the question is not about git