# Visual studio code, exclude directory from "go to file" option (ctrl + p)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode, and I would like to exclude some directories (with webpack bundles) from 'go to file' option in vscode.

I tried to exclude them by "search.exclude" and "files.exclude". That worked in files tree and in search, but I still can find these files by 'go to file'.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33418660/139. Also, just use the [vscode] tag:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choose folders to be ignored during search in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 33):

As @adamesque stated, to exclude files from quick open you can either add them to `files.exclude` or `search.exclude` setting.
The issue then is that **Quick Open** also stores `recent items`, even from excluded paths.

Fortunately, VSCode now have a command **File: Clear Recently Opened**!

EDIT: As I needed to replace a Disk path while keeping my recent files I found where they are stored. It's in the storage.json file which is under `/Users/imac/Library/Application Support/Code/storage.json` on macOS and `AppData\Roaming\Code\storage.json` on Windows.

Answer (score 11):

I thought I had this exact problem, and all the relevant issues I could find in the VS Code GitHub project seemed to have been fixed (see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19029, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6502).

In my case, because I had previously opened some of the files in those excluded directories, they still showed up in "Go To File" in the "Recently Opened" section, which made me think the exclusion feature wasn't working.

Turns out I just had to manually remove those items from history to keep them from showing up. Open the Command Palette, run `Remove from History`, and then select the a file to remove. You may need to do this for each file you'd previously opened from an "excluded" dir, but after this is done, they shouldn't show up anymore in the "Go to File" menu.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

Version 1.44:

now we have an option in the settings.

If you tipe "Goto file" in the setting search bar, the editor opens up a Search:Exclude section, and you can add a folder or files.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P`, then select `File: Clear Recently Opened`

Answer (score 0):

As @melMass suggests Clearing history has also the benefit that when you use Go to file (i.e. Ctrl+p) it gives results from your project as well as from history. So a lot of times history contains a file name similar to our project file and you wonder why my code is not working; when in fact you are working in the wrong file.

So clear history as often as you can to avoid this confusion.