# How to avoid index.d.ts files when look up for definition?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I enabled a webpack alias in my jsconfig.json file for VSCode.

But when I go to definition of a React component, I get 2 definitions:

1. my react component
2. an index.d.ts file of node_modules/@types/react

How do I get rid of the index.d.ts file ? Knowing that I use only jsx.

Comment: That is a very good question!

Comment: See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066316/visual-studio-code-exclude-directory-from-go-to-file-option-ctrl-p

Answer (score 2):

All of the components in the project are written using the React.FC type and are automatically exported.

One way to fix an issue with the **"Goto Location: Multiple Definitions"** feature in the Editor is to change the configuration from **peek** to **goto**.

[image]

This may hide some additional definitions that may be useful, but it will make the feature work as intended when clicking on components.

Comment: Good! This is more of a workaround to the actual problem. Not sure how will this work when you have 2 legit definitions

Comment: This has made is so much worse for me now, 98% of the time I end up in the index.d.ts file. Any wat to remove index.d.ts files as a possible option?