# Visual Studio Code | Exclude temporary FTP files from the fuzzy search

Tags: visual-studio-code, fuzzy-search

As the title says, I would like to exclude temporary FTP files from the fuzzy search.

The files to exclude are in the following directory: C:/Users/[USER]/AppData/Local/Temp/*

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/how-can-i-choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search

Comment: @AlexandervanTrijffel not working, it still shows up in the fuzzy searchfinder

Answer (score 0):

You can add the temp variable to the exclude for the project like this:

```
// .vscode/settings.json
  "search.exclude": {
    "%TEMP%": true
  }
```