# How to exclude all files in one of the multi-root workspace folders for searching in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a multi-root workspace set up, in which two out of the four folders are external thus I can't add specific settings to that folder. I would like to disable search on those folders, preferably in the workspace settings.

I couldn't find the right pattern to make that work :(

Below are my workspace settings, I am trying to filter files in the out folder:

```
"folders": [
    {
        "name": "Application"
        "path": "./application"
    },
    {
        "name": "Device"
        "path": "./device"
    },
    {
        "name": "Out"
        "path": "./out"
    }],
"settings": {
    // Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in searches. Inherits all glob patterns from the files.exclude setting.
    "search.exclude": {
        "out": true,
        "**/tests": true,
        ".tags": true
    },
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem right now. I'm using the remote workspace extension and search is not working because of my remote workdspace (ftp). I too would like to disable search on this particular workspace root so, the search can can work again.

Answer (score -1):

As proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33418660/6225923, you can use the workspace settings and add patterns for folders to exclude, like this:

```
"search.excludeFolders": [
    "folder1",
    "folder2",
    "folder3",
    "path/to/other/folder4"
],
```

Additionally, make sure the search exlusion is still active is the settings.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work.  Below are my workspace settings:
"folders": [
  {
      "name": "Application"
   "path": "./application"
  },
  {
      "name": "Device"
   "path": "./device"
  },
  {
      "name": "Out"
   "path": "./out"
  }],
 "settings": {
        // Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in searches. Inherits all glob patterns from the files.exclude setting.
     "search.exclude": {
   "out": true,
   "**/tests": true,
   ".tags": true
     },