# Visual Studio Code: Search Within Files but Exclude Folder

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code (not to be confused with Visual Studio) there is a search interface (click the mag glass at top left).

It has a "files to include" field, and a "files to exclude" field.

I know that I can include or exclude a **file** from my search by entering the name of the file, or using a wildcard like *.js.

Is there a way to specifically include or exclude a **directory** by using these fields? If not, how would I do that?

Edit:
Some have said that this question may be similar to [How can I choose folders to be ignored during search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/how-can-i-choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search)

I think it is fundamentally the same question, but as I said in a recent comment on that question: 
"There is nothing in the title of this question to indicate that you are asking a question about a specific tool (Visual Studio Code). And while you do have it tagged `visual-studio-code` - making it appear in searches about that tool - the searcher will not necessarily know that this question is about VS Code. Also, you use a Mac specific keyboard command that is not really relevant to the question at hand, and makes the question seem non-relevant to non-Mac users."

So, yes, I guess it's the same question. But I don't think it's reasonable to expect me to have found it.

Comment: Take a look at this, its the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33418660/8726546

Comment: Just putting the folder name in the "files to exclude/include" boxes works for me - you don't need to do anything special for folders.

Comment: I searched, but I didn't see that other question. Anyway, thank you both for the info.

Comment: I just made a suggested edit to [How can I choose folders to be ignored during search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/how-can-i-choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search) to clarify that it involves Visual Studio Code. Hopefully, people will find it in the future. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I choose folders to be ignored during search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/how-can-i-choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search)

Comment: see answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/how-can-i-choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could either change the global settings (CTRL + , by default), for example to ignore anything in node_modules

```json
"search.exclude": {
  "**/node_modules": true
}
```

Or if you don't want to set a global setting, you can just add the `foldername\*` to the "files to exclude" field. So in our example

`files to exclude node_modules\*`

Hope this helps anyone searching for it in the future.

---

For reference:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options

Answer (score 1):

[Update 1.73.1](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_73#_include-and-exclude-folders-from-search) finally addresses this issue and provides an easy way to include/exclude folders in the tree view

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude or include a folder by using the files to include/exclude text boxes.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17164#issuecomment-311750417