# How to keep bundle.js or other build files out of visual studio code search results?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to find a specific method or code block by searching all files in visual studio code. I often get results from bundle.js or bundle.js.map. These really don't do me any good and get in the way. Is there some way to keep them out of the results?

[image]

Comment: press the `...` button and fill in the files to exclude, see the doc for the glob syntax supported

Comment: check this url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search-in-vs-code