# VSC: Refactor in user source folders only

Tags: visual-studio-code, refactoring

In Visual Studio Code 1.68.1. under Ubuntu 22.04, whenever I try to refactor (rename, F2) a variable, it searches through all the files under the project tree. Then it suggests in the preview the ones that are actually involved. It's correct, but exploring all the files may take a lot of time.

Is there a way to tell VSC to look at the user source files only? I mean the ones under `include` and `src`? Or, even better, select (or exclude) directories for refactoring?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search-in-vs-code) question, but it's related to a search rather than a refactoring.

Comment: @rioV8, I added the extension tag because perhaps there is an extension that provides a better refactoring feature

Comment: that is not what that tag is for