# VSCode refuses to ignore folder in Search feature

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a NextJS project that I'd like to disable searching for text in the `.next` folder.

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search-in-vs-code), I've added this to my preferences:

[image]

But still, I'm getting search results for that folder:

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Does it work as you expect if there are no files from the `.next` folder open?  There is an issue with vscode searching in open files even if they would otherwise be excluded by the `searc.exclude` setting.

Answer (score 0):

##### Have you tried excluding it just for the current search?

That works for me very easily. Here, I am searching for a div tag in a web project that has hundreds of them. If I exclude the "src" folder, none are found.

[image]

##### The approach you are taking is a *persistent* exclusion, which is more tricky

It is more tricky because there are ways of *accidentally* disabling your global exclusions.

From the VS Code help:

> VS Code excludes some folders by default to reduce the number of
> search results that you are not interested in (for example:
> node_modules). Open settings to change these rules under the
> files.exclude and search.exclude section.
>
> Note that glob patterns in the search view work differently than in
> settings such as files.exclude and search.exclude. In the settings,
> you must use **/example to match a folder named example in subfolder
> folder1/example in your workspace. In the search view, the ** prefix
> is assumed. The glob patterns in these settings are always evaluated
> relative to the path of the workspace folder.
>
> Also note the Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files toggle button in
> the files to exclude box. The toggle determines whether to exclude
> files that are ignored by your .gitignore files and/or matched by your
> files.exclude and search.exclude settings.

That last paragraph is the potential trap. I think it says, if you de-toggle it, then even though you have told VS Code in the settings to exclude ".next", it will nevertheless search everything including ".next".