# I am receiving 'An error occurred reading file.' error in Bicep

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-bicep

User
I used the following code in main.bicep:

```
var groupAndPrincipalIDs = loadJsonContent('../groupAndPrincipalIDs.json')
```

I have 4 pipelines which one of them is creating the 'groupAndPrincipalIDs.json' and the other will use this bicep file to deploy azure resources. So right now the folder which contains the main.Bicep dose not have  'groupAndPrincipalIDs.json' . And VS Code is showing me an error and complaining that '*`An error occurred reading file. Could not find file 'c:\UserX\**Repo**\groupAndPrincipalIDs.json`*', is there any setting in VS Code for Bicep to ignore this erro?

I created a .vscode folder (not in the Repo itself but, in one level up) and i added the following content in settings.json:

```
{
     "bicep.build.targetScope": "file",
     "bicep.build.file": "main.bicep",
     "bicep.build.onFileOpen": {
        "ignoreFileNotFound": ["../groupAndPrincipalIDs.json"]
     }
}
```

which it did not work

Comment: Does vscode not having the Json file which you've given? @Tara Behtouei

Comment: Or you need to give the path of that Json file in the current main.bicep to ignore that error. @Tara Behtouei

Comment: vscode dose not have the Json file which you've given.
and i need to give the path of that Json file in the current main.bicep to ignore that error. @Jahnavi

Comment: Did you give the path you are saying? Did it work? @Tara Behtouei

Comment: The thing is this Json file will create as an artifact in one of my stages inside the Azure Pipeline, and it will be available for this bicep which will be the next stage in the pipeline.
It will download the artifact and will use it inside the Bicep as i wrote in the main.bicep.
So it should not be in my local computer. @Jahnavi

Comment: This is why i need to ignor it, because it will be there in the hosted agent for Azure pipeline.

Comment: `{
  "bicep.build.onFileOpen": {
    "ignoreFileNotFound": ["../groupAndPrincipalIDs.json"]
  }
}`  To ignore it, add this in `.vscode/settings.json` file. @Tara Behtouei

Comment: Did you try with this? @Tara Behtouei

Comment: Yes I tried that as well, did not work. I do not know what i did wrong. @Jahnavi

Comment: Another approach you can try is "files to exclude" in vscode user/workspace settings. Refer [VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) document for the related information & [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33418660/19785512). @Tara Behtouei

Comment: Check this [blog](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/exclude-folders-from-search-in-vscode) as well. @Tara Behtouei

Comment: It did not work as well, but thanks for your time any way. @Jahnavi

Comment: Have you tried any other way? @Tara Behtouei

Comment: Still are you facing the same issue? @Tara Behtouei

Comment: Hi @Jahnavi, sorry for delay answer.
I also created the bicepconfig.json and added what I had in settings.json. It did not work either.